# Update Array of Objects using cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi i'm new to cloud functions, i was trying to update **name** in the collection when there is a Chang(update) on family document, but i cannot update **name**  in the collection, seems like line is not executing after first console log.

```
exports.onClassroomUpdate = functions.firestore.document("family/{id}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
const documentId = context.params.id;
const after = change.after.data(); 
let users = admin.firestore().collection('users').where('family.id', '==', documentId);

    return users.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        let chain = Promise.resolve();
        console.log('work');
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log('not working');
            chain = chain.then(() => {
                return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(doc.id).update({
                    name: after.name
                });
            });
        });

        return Promise.all([chain]);

    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
});
)}
```

[image]

Comment: how do you know which id into the family map you want to update?

Comment: It looks like the query you're trying to perform isn't possible.  It's returning no documents, and you can't reach into objects with names you don't know ahead of time.  For example, the (shortened) field path of the first id value is `family.3Z5h--yFlL.id`.  You can't skip the middle part.